# Unable to stop tomcat server

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have Tomcat 7 running on a virtual machine running Linux. I started Tomcat as foreground process using a script and don’t know how to stop it. I have tried `stop`, `restart`, `start` but all of the are giving me same error message:

`status` command:

```
 UNKNOWN due to Tomcat 7-based instance being started as a foreground process
```

`stop` command:

```
 Unable to stop Tomcat 7-based instance that was started as a foreground process. Use CTRL+C in the console of the process to stop the instance
```

Any idea how can I stop the foreground Tomcat instance?

Comment: The filesystem for your logs might be 100% full. Please verify that, do the clean up and then try to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Init scripts work just if you start it by themselves so they record and use later the PID (Process ID.

you could try with:

```
killall -9 tomcat
```

Or give `pstree` command and see which script or what is starting Tomcat and kill that one aswell.

Comment: how i can find the foreground process instance?

Comment: "ps axwu | grep tomcat" will show you all the instances. You can then check the tty associated to see the foreground one or check the lowest pid and so on to see the main istance.